# Near/radar/ray/collision sensors refuse to work

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

None of the physics sensors in my game work, I'm trying to create an AI man that chases after a player, but for whatever reason, he just won't sense the player, I've tried copying and pasting the property name *just* to be sure, but that's not it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the **Actor** option physics tab for your player so it can be detected by the **Near** and **Radar** sensors :

[image]

Comment: you're a life saver chebhou! thanks! how could i miss something so simple?