# How do I use near sensor in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

in BGE, I have set up a near sensor for enemy tracking, however, it won't do anything, so I'm wondering if I did something wrong, I don't know if I have to attach a file, but if I do, for this question to be answered, I have it on a filehost link already to upload it
The duplicate questions answer is not working, however I do have the exact same problem

Comment: Share the link.

Comment: This is the preferred blend sharing site: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: see if this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31579/near-radar-ray-collision-sensors-refuse-to-work